# Change start frame of a background movie clip?

Tags: animation

I added a "Background Image" and selected "Movie clip".
Now I am wondering if it is possible to change the start frame.

[image]

I am animating a character and I need the movie clip to start at a specific frame.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Movie Clip* is a special data type in Blender. To change its properties you would have to go the *Movie Clip Editor*, open up the clip there, open the properties panel (<kbd>N</kbd>), go to footage settings and add an offset there in order to change the start frame.

However, if you only want to have a background video, I would advise you not to use the *Movie Clip* type. Instead, click on 'Image', and open up your video. There you can also adjust the offset in order to change the video's startframe.

[image]

Comment: If I try to load a mp4 file as image, then it does not appear. (All Views is set)

Comment: Hm, that's odd. And loading it as MovieClip works?

Comment: Yes MovieClips works. I think this is a bug. I am using blender 2.79. I will turn my computer off an on again later and try it again, this helped me sometimes.